# Multivaritate version of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: number-theory, cyclic-groups

If $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $d$, then

$$g(x)^{p^d} \equiv g(x) \bmod f(x)$$ and $p^d - 1$ is the order of the cyclic group $\left( \mathbb{F}_p[x]/f(x) \right)^{\times}$. Is there a multivariate version of this?

Comment: you mean in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ ? And since $G =(\mathbb{F}_p[x]/f(x))^{\times}$ is a finite group, $g(x)^{|G|} = 1$ in the group, this is [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). so the point of the Fermat or [Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) is to say explicitly what is $|G|$

Comment: @user1952009 yes $\Bbb F_q[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ (may be there is an analogy here)?

Comment: not sure, but $|G|$ might be very complicated to compute  in the case of  $\mathbb{F}_q[x,y] / (f(x,y))$, the problem being that $\mathbb{F}_q[x,y]$ is not a principal ideal domain, so $f$ irreducible doesn't mean it is a field, or something like that

Comment: [Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications)  and $\{g^a \mid a = 1,2,\ldots\}$ is a cyclic subgroup..